# Flexbox gap workaround for Safari

Tags: flexbox, safari

I finished my website but I didn't realize that safari doesn't support the flexbox gap. Is there a way around this without having the mess anything up? This is mostly for my media queries.

```html
<div class="social-media">
  <a href="https://github.com/">
    <img class="social-media__icon" src="img/github.png" alt="Github">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
    <img class="social-media__icon" src="img/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn">
  </a>
</div>
```

```css
.social-media {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8rem;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.social-media img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px; 
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .social-media {
        gap: 3rem;
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }
    .social-media img {
        width: 62px;
        height: 62px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the **Lobotomized** owl selector: `.parent > * + * {}` to add a margin-left that gives you space between the elements that come after another element, this way you eliminate the undesired margin it creates when you put the margin directly to the child's first element (`.social-media img{}`)

```
    .social-media > * + * { margin-left: 8rem;}
```

Here you can read more about the [Lobotomized Owl Selector](https://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls/)

Edit: Gap is now supported in Safari 14.1 (Sep 2021) so you should be able to use it no problem.

Comment: Neither gap nor column-gap were working for me in Safari, still. This worked like a charm though.

Comment: just in case you are wondering how to use that inside **mui**, we could simply do at the parent element:
`'& > *+*': { marginTop: '16px' }`

Comment: It was working fine on Safari. Great.

Comment: gap works both vertically and horizontally. What about when we have a lot of items that creates line breaks ? left margin won't behave like expected

Comment: @KCarnaille adding margin-right (including on the first one) would probably give the best result in that case, every first element in the new line will start at the same place vertically but will have a space on the right that will still be equal if the items are the same width, which is just like flex-wrap behaviour, you could also maybe play with negative margins/paddings on the container to eliminate the unwanted end of line space

Answer (score 11):

Property `gap` with `display: flex` is not supported by Safar version < 14 https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap .
You might want to replace display `flex` with `grid`:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 8rem; /* Safari 10-11 */
gap: 8rem;      /* Safari 12+ */
```

because grid's gap is supported in older Safari versions: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_gap_grid_context

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the comments from KCarnaille and Elazar Zadiki to the answer suggesting the lobotomized owl selector, I believe the following CSS rules do a better job as a fallback to the use of the `column-gap` and `row-gap` properties along with flexbox:

```css
.flex-container {
  --column-gap: 5px; 
  --row-gap: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Remove the margin created by the last row of flex items */
  margin-bottom: calc(-1 * var(--column-gap));
  /* Remove the margin created by the last flex item in each row */
  margin-right: calc(-1 * var(--row-gap));
}
.flex-container > .flex-item {
  margin-bottom: var(--row-gap);
  margin-right: var(--column-gap);
}
```

Of course, if you would otherwise use the `gap` property, set the same value for `--column-gap` and `--row-gap` above.

Comment: Maybe there is an inversion? I think that the margin bottom of flex container should depends on row-gap and margin right should depend on column-gap

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has the problem, that you will have a wrong margin on the first element if when there is only one row. Also centered elements will always be 8rem too far the right.

Better solution that will always work with correct spacings:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  // the trick is to set margins around boxes, but correct the margins around elements that are situated at the border of the container with negative margins
  margin: 0 -10px -20px -10px;
}

.box {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: deeppink;
  margin: 0 10px 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'>1</div>
  <div class='box'>2</div>
  <div class='box'>3</div>
  <div class='box'>4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the gap class and add another one to child elements

```
<div class="d-flex"> // it was "d-flex gap" previously
  <div class="mx-2">
    //content
  </div>
  <div class="mx-2">
    //content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could make a div container and put justify-content: space-between; then i think it should work

Comment: where do i put the div?  I tried something and its not working

Comment: put the div around the items that need a gap and then put display: flex; and justify-content: space-between; on it. then make the width of each item something like 30% if it's three items and the remaining percent will be the gap in between.