# CSS navigation bar spacing issue on iPad

Tags: css, ios

I have an issue where the items on my navigation bar are not properly spaced out when displayed on an iPad.

I have tested on desktop and laptop but for some reason it does not correctly adjust for the iPad.

On desktop, it appears correctly:

[image]

But on my iPad, it looks like this:

[image]

My CSS:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 100000;
  }
  
    .nav-links {
      font-weight: 600;
      display:flex;
      gap: 1em;      
 }
```

And HTML:

```
  <nav>
    <div class='nav-logo'>
      <a href="index.html#top"><img src='images/White_on_Transparent.png' id='nav-img'></a>
    </div>
    <ul class='nav-links'>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href = #SERVICES><button class="dropdown-button">SERVICES</button></a>
        </li>
      <li><a href="index.html#about-me">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#PORTFOLIO">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#FOOTER">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>    
  </nav>
```

I tried adjusting `gap` under the `.nav_links` section but this did not change anything.

In responsive testing in Google Chrome, it also works correctly with no issues. I have not checked other devices such as other tablets yet.

Do I need to specifically adjust with media queries? I am stumped as to why this is happening.

Comment: I did try that just now but unfortunately it didn't change anything?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the classes to the HTML. Maybe the `nav`'s `flex` is forcing that gap to close in the `nav-link`'s flex? Maybe `flex-shrink: 0;` will help prevent this?

Comment: Are you using Safari, if so what version? https://windowsreport.com/gap-not-working-safari/

Comment: I am definitely using an older version than 14. Is there a workaround for older versions? I tried `flex-shrink: 0;` in both `nav` and `.nav_links` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I found this answer "Use the Lobotomized owl selector: .parent > * + * {} to add a margin-left " here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452057/flexbox-gap-workaround-for-safari . Unfortunately I don't  have Safari to try it myself but hope it helps get you started

Comment: Another option depending on safari version is the use of grid, from the same link in another answer

Comment: I see, thank you. How would I apply this to the above? With `.nav` or `.nav_links`? I am new to most of this so I am a little confused with it.

Comment: My first guess would be `.nav-links`. So each link gets a margin added to it. That was my understanding from the answer but I could be wrong. Hope it works out

Comment: yes that worked! Thank you! I have been searching for hours for the answer. Will it still work for newer versions of Safari? Or will they get messed up by using this selector?

Comment: Glad it worked! in general properties will work on newer versions. A good resource for checking css usage in versions is https://caniuse.com/ . Type in the property you want to use and it tell you which browsers support it.

Comment: Maybe you can add your working code here as an answer? Would really like to see if the solution from that other answer works the way I was thinking it did. Thanks

Comment: Good idea, will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated below and with the assistance mentioned in the comments, this question was solved using the Lobotomized owl selector: `.parent > * + * {}` to add a margin-left  from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452057/flexbox-gap-workaround-for-safari).

I currently am using an older version of Safari hence the suggested workaround.

My updated CSS is:

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 100000;
   }
  
    .nav-links {
      font-weight: 600;
      display:flex;           
   }

    .nav-links > * + * { margin-left: 0.7rem;}
```