# CSS scroll margin issue on older versions of Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

This is a similar question to the one I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77102090/css-navigation-bar-spacing-issue-on-ipad).

I am having an issue with using scroll margin on older versions of Safari when I link it to a section on my page. According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/), it is supported.

My HTML:

```
<div class="section-invoice" id = "invoice">    
        <div class="text">       
          <h3>HEADING</h3>    
            <p>Some text.</p>   
        </div>            
      </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
   #invoice {
       scroll-margin-top: 150px;
       border: solid blue;
    }  
  }
```

I also read that changing this to `scroll-snap-margin-top` would resolve the issue, however nothing changed.

Is there something else required for older versions of Safari?